# Error while generate Java client for Zoom Swagger/OpenAPI spec

Tags: java, api, rest, swagger-codegen, zoom-sdk

In our test project (Spring Boot app) we would like to use Zoom API. So we tried to generate Java client using [swagger `codegen` and `Zoom Swagger/OpenAPI` spec](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/Zoom%20API.oas2.json)
But looks like it generates the client with some errors.

So we run the following to generate java client:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.7.jar generate -i https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/Zoom%20API.oas2.json -l java
```

It generates the code, but when I build it, several compilation problem occurred, e.g.

```
symbol:   class object
location: class MeetingsApi
C:\GIT\test-app\src\main\java\io\swagger\client\api\MeetingsApi.java:1643: error: cannot find symbol
       public com.squareup.okhttp.Call meetingRegistrantQuestionUpdateCall(Integer meetingId, object body, final ProgressResponseBody.ProgressListener progressListener, final ProgressRequestBody.ProgressRequestListener progressRequestListener) throws ApiException {
```

Is it possible to generate Java client from “Zoom API.oas2.json”?
Or maybe it’s possible to use some Zoom SDK for Java, to avoid using plain `Unirest`/`OkHttp`?

Comment: Open an issue at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues

Comment: Asker moved to Zoom Developer Forum: https://devforum.zoom.us/t/can-not-generate-java-client-for-swagger-openapi-spec

Comment: The swagger json file is fixed now. https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/Zoom%20API.oas2.json